# Procedure or function 'xyz' has too many arguments specified

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, formview

I know this type of question has been asked at least a dozen times on SO, but I've gone through all the previous questions and answers I could find here and none that I have found apply. I am using several FormView objects on my page and now want to add the option to edit one of them.  The FormView is populated by SqlDataSource linked to a stored procedure, so I made a stored procedure to update the records and added it to the SqlDataSource, which now looks like this:

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="TestSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
                   SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:development %>" 
                   SelectCommand="usp_GetNewTestDetails" 
                   UpdateCommand="usp_UpdateTest" 
                   UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
                   onupdating="TestSqlDataSource_Updating">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="TestID" Name="TestID"/>
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="testId" Type="Int32"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="testerLicense" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="premiseOwner" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="premiseAddress" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="premiseCity" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="premiseState" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="premiseZip" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="protectionType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="testType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="repairs" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="notes" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="testDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="employerName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="employerAddress" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="phoneNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="emailAddress" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="dataEntryName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="dataEntryPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="signature" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="entryDate" Type="DateTime" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When I attempt to update a record, I'm getting an error that says there are too many parameters in my query.  I have triple checked that the parameters in my code match exactly (name, number, and even order) to the ones in my stored procedure.

In attempting to find answers, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5757120/933524) which referenced [this site](http://web.archive.org/web/20120606031904/http://www.whitworth.org/2006/01/16/how-to-troubleshoot-procedure-or-function-has-too-many-arguments-specified-in-aspnet-20/) (had to go to archive.org because the original appears to be down).  I applied what they suggested for adding the parameters to the `trace` function.  What I found was that in my stored procedure, there are a few "lookup" values from the select procedure that aren't in the update procedure.  The table I'm trying to update only has the ID of the tester, but the users would like to see their name as well, so it references that table, but in the FormView those fields are read-only during edit mode so they can't attempt to change it.  All the other parameters line up... only those lookup values are off.

I thought that by including the specific list of parameters to pass that it would only use those parameters, but that appears to be incorrect.  Now I'm stumped because I have already specified the parameters, and I can't see anywhere that they are being overwritten with the ones from the select stored procedure.  Where do I tell it not to use those read-only values?

I don't want to remove them from the original stored procedure because they will be needed by the users.  The one workaround that I have come up with so far is to add them to the stored procedure and then just never use them.  Although I'm fairly certain this would work, it is very much just covering up the problem rather than fixing it.

---

**EDIT:** Additional code, per request

This is the method that outputs the parameters to the `trace` function:

```cs
protected void TestSqlDataSource_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Command.Parameters.Count; i++)
    {
        Trace.Write(e.Command.Parameters[i].ParameterName);
        if (e.Command.Parameters[i].Value != null)
        {
            Trace.Write(e.Command.Parameters[i].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is the stored procedure used for updating:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateTest]
    @testId INT ,
    @testerLicense INT ,
    @premiseOwner VARCHAR(50) ,
    @premiseAddress VARCHAR(150) ,
    @premiseCity VARCHAR(50) ,
    @premiseState VARCHAR(2) ,
    @premiseZip VARCHAR(10) ,
    @protectionType VARCHAR(11) ,
    @testType VARCHAR(2) ,
    @repairs VARCHAR(200) ,
    @notes VARCHAR(300) ,
    @testDate DATETIME ,
    @employerName VARCHAR(50) ,
    @employerAddress VARCHAR(150) ,
    @phoneNumber VARCHAR(25) ,
    @emailAddress VARCHAR(60) ,
    @dataEntryName VARCHAR(50) ,
    @dataEntryPhone VARCHAR(25) ,
    @signature VARCHAR(50) ,
    @entryDate DATETIME
AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        UPDATE  dbo.Tests
        SET     TesterLicense = @testerLicense ,
                PremiseOwner = @premiseOwner ,
                PremiseAddress = @premiseAddress ,
                PremiseCity = @premiseCity ,
                PremiseState = @premiseState ,
                PremiseZip = @premiseZip ,
                ProtectionType = @protectionType ,
                TestType = @testType ,
                Repairs = @repairs ,
                Notes = @notes ,
                TestDate = @testDate ,
                EmployerName = @employerName ,
                EmployerAddress = @employerAddress ,
                PhoneNumber = @phoneNumber ,
                EmailAddress = @emailAddress ,
                DataEntryName = @dataEntryName ,
                DataEntryPhone = @dataEntryPhone ,
                Signature = @signature ,
                EntryDate = @entryDate 
        WHERE TestID = @testId
    END
```

Comment: Did you check if there are any spelling errors or data type conversion error?

Comment: @RuchiRahulDoshi Yes.  I copied both sets of parameters into Excel and went line by line comparing.  That was the most common problem in this all-too-common question here, so I was very careful to ensure they were exact.  Having used `trace` to display all the parameters it is passing, I can tell for sure that it is actually passing too many arguments, but I don't know how to turn it off.

Comment: Would you please paste your "usp_UpdateTest" and "TestSqlDataSource_Updating" here if you dont mind.

Comment: @RuchiRahulDoshi Added the requested code.

Comment: I can suggest you one thing, that for each update parameter on the _updating event specify it one by one like  
  
e.Command.Parameters["@testerLicense"].Value = value  -- so if there is an issue that it is taking more parameters it would be restricted by the no. of parameters specified here.

Comment: I see that u have mentioned that u already tried this approach. I am looking for more options for your problem correction. Update u if I find some good matter on the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out on my own.  It was related to the fact that Visual Studio created the templates for me based on the stored procedure's schema.  When the templates are autogenerated, every textbox in the `<EditItemTemplate>` section gets generated like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TestIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TestID") %>'/>
```

Turns out that it is the `Bind` statement that caused this.  VS automatically creates a parameter for any field populated using `Bind`.  Although I was led to believe that the `<UpdateParameters>` section should have overridden this, it was actually the other way around.  I was able to prevent these few read-only fields from passing back their parameters by changing the code on those fields from `Bind` to `Eval`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TestIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TestID") %>'/>
```

Works perfectly now.

---

**Addendum:**

Found that this causes the same problem in the other direction as well.  If you mark a field you don't want edited as `Eval` but it needs to be included in the update (such as a row ID) it will not work, this time for too few parameters.  I'm wondering now what the purpose of the `<UpdateParameters>` section even is, since it doesn't seem to follow anything in there...

Comment: I tried your solution, replacing Bind with Eval. It doesn't give me the error 'Procedure or function 'xyz' has too many arguments specified' anymore but data is not updated

Comment: @ThandoTee You don't want to replace *all* the `Bind` statements with `Eval`, only the few that are not supposed to update the data.  `Eval` is a read-only command, so it will not update those fields.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution you came up with.  I'm not an ASP programmer but it will allow me to help others when SQL Server coughs up sucn an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete unwanted parameters during e.g OnDeleting event (e.Command.Parameters.RemoveAt(i)).